# Microsoft CRM WebApplication USD

Tags: customization, crm

Hi I am now working in Microsoft CRM Customization. I am following the tutorial which describes about web application adapter in USD.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn864880.aspx

I am getting the QSWebApplication as in the tutorial. Now I need to place the QsWebApplication in left side menu of the Dashboard. Is it possible to do? If so How to do?

[image: Sample Expected Output]

**Sample Expected Output**

[image: Sample Expected Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Venkat,

You have to change the display group for the hosted control dedicated for this external application. Change that to LeftPanelFill. Right now it should MainPanel. Since it is already loading, you dont have to make any changes to the action call.

Hope this clarifies your query. Let us know if you face any issue on the same.

NB: Please ignore my previous answer as that was a misunderstanding from my part.